# Finding sum through eager loading

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I've a table schema as follows:

```
+----+---------------+------------+--------+
| id | crowd_fund_id |   email    | amount |
+----+---------------+------------+--------+
|  1 |            11 | jj@xx.com  |    200 |
|  2 |            11 | sd@ff.com  |    250 |
|  3 |            12 | jj@xx.com  |    150 |
|  4 |            12 | abc@cc.com |    230 |
+----+---------------+------------+--------+
```

And a `Entries` table:

```
+----+---------+----------+------+
| id | user_id | crowd_id | name |
+----+---------+----------+------+
|  1 |       6 |       11 | Abc  |
|  2 |       6 |       12 | Xyc  |
|  3 |       8 |       18 | ijn  |
+----+---------+----------+------+
```

In the Backer's Model

```
public function entry()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Entries', 'crowd_fund_id', 'crowd_id');
    }
```

and in the Controller I've called:

```
$var = Backers::with('entry')->where('email', $user->email)->get();
```

This works fine. Now I wanted to get the `sum` also through the eager loading. 
That means I need to call something like

```
Backers::with('entry')->with('sum')->where('email', $user->email)->get();
```

The `sum` will calculate the total of all the `amount` where `crowd_fund_id` is equal to the raw where `email = $user->email`.
That means when I call

```
Backers::with('entry')->with('sum')->where('email', $user->email)->get();
```

I should be getting :
1 raw for the backer's details with `crowd_fund_id`
1 raw for the corresponding entry where `crowd_fund_id = crowd_id`
1 sum of all `amount` where `crowd_fund_id = crowd_fund_id` from the backer's details.

How can I get this?

Comment: Can you show your table schema?

Comment: `Backer` table:
`[id----crowd_fund_id---email---name]`

Comment: Can you not call something along the lines of `$this->id` to get the id of the current model you are calling?

Comment: @honerlawd: I tried that. But says `undefined property`

Answer (score 1):

Could you try something along these lines (in your Backers model):

```
public function backersSum()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Backer')
        ->selectRaw('crowd_fund_id, sum(amount) as aggregate')
        ->groupBy('crowd_fund_id');
}
```

Doing it this way allows you to eager load it like any relationship. Then you could do something like this to access it:

```
public function getBackersSumAttribute()
{
  if ( ! $this->relationLoaded('backersSum')) 
    $this->load('backersSum');

  $related = $this->getRelation('backersSum');

  return ($related) ? (int) $related->aggregate : 0;
}
```

Comment: I put both your function in the Backers Model. and then from the controller called this: 

`$donations = Backers::with('entry')->with('getBackersSumAttribute')->where('email', $user->email)->get();`

Result: `column not found: backers.backers_id`. 

So I added `return $this->hasOne('App\Backers', 'id')....`

then result: `Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on a non-object`

Comment: Instead of `with('getBackersSumAttribute')`, you should just do `with('backersSum')`. Here's the link to the docs about accessors http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators

Comment: Seems getting the output. But the Sum is always null :/

Comment: Do you have debugbar (https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar) installed to see what queries are getting run? Also, you should just try and insert some dd() inside the functions to see what is being returned. I use this type of code all the time in my projects and it works for me...

Comment: This: `'select crowd_fund_id, sum(amount) as aggregate from 'backers' where 'backers'.'id' in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) group by 'crowd_fund_id''`

Comment: I think the function `getBackersSumAttribute` is not being called.

Comment: You might need to change the `return $this->hasOne('App\Backer')` to `return $this->hasOne('App\Backer', 'id', 'crowd_fund_id')` or something. I wonder if you're selecting the right IDs, and unfortunately, I still don't quite see clearly how your tables are laid out. See (http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#one-to-one)

Comment: I've updated the question with more details. Can you check now?